# How to validate textbox input

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to make expression in Custom Validator if input is array of 'A' 'G' 'C' 'T' isValid=true otherwise isValid=false in C#(ASP.NET)? For windows form app i made this i need something similar

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = 
      char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && ((e.KeyChar == 65) || (e.KeyChar == 67) || 
                   (e.KeyChar == 71) || (e.KeyChar == 84) || (e.KeyChar == 97) || 
                   (e.KeyChar == 99) || (e.KeyChar == 103) || (e.KeyChar == 116)) ||
                   (e.KeyChar == 8) ? false : true;   
}
```

For validation i have this

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate1(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        Match validate = Regex.Match(TextBox1.ToString(), "[AGCT]");
        if (validate.Success)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else args.IsValid = false;
        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show a [mcve] of your existing progress on the custom validator.

Comment: ASP.NET event handling is not same as windows application event handling. You need to handle this using client side script such as JavaScript and JQuery.

Comment: In Asp.Net, you should use the buildin validator-controls for this. The RegularExpressionValidator is perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

No problem!

In ASP.Net, you'll handle this validation in Javascript. So, your input element will be declared like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyField)
```

Then you'll use Javascript to perform the validation by handling the keyup event.

e.preventDefault() is the equivalent of your e.Handled in WinForms:

```
document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(m => m.MyField)').onkeyup = function (e) {
    if(~[65, 67, 71, 84, 97, 99, 103, 116, 8].indexOf(e.keyCode || e.which)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Also, I have no idea why you were downvoted, your question is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: The question is about Asp.Net Web Forms and not Mvc.

Comment: @Esko, while this is implied by his current approach, it is not explicitly stated. Also, you can use Razor pages without MVC; this is called ASP.Net WebPages.